# Determining Moves and Outcomes for Tic-Tac-Toe in MATLAB W/ Helper Function

Tags: string, matlab, helper, tic-tac-toe, cell-array

Note: I am up-dating this as I go along. I add in comments to let you know if I added in code or not. Since I have no comments, I doubt anyone will get confused. And to whomever down-voted me, I'm putting in as much information as I can. Calm yourself.

That's a pretty long title, but it sums up everything I need to do for this problem. I am given a tic-tac-toe board in the form of a 3x3 cell and a string that tells me whose move it is (Player X or Player O). I need to out a 2xN cell that lists what possible moves can be made, and what the outcome of that move would be. For example, the the player is Player X and my board looks like:

```
       { 'x' 'o' 'x'
         'o' 'x' 'o'
         'o' ' ' ' ' }
```

Then my options are

```
    { 'x' 'o' 'x'              {'x' 'o' 'x'
      'o' 'x' 'o'              'o' 'x' 'o'
      'o' 'x' ' '}             'o' ' ' 'x'}
 'Your move, player O.'       'Player X Wins!' }
```

Blanks spots are always indicated by a space. Now for this problem, I've been given a helper function called 'moveEvaluater' that looks like this:

```
 Helper Function Name: moveEvaluator
 Helper Function Inputs (2): - (char) A 3x3 character array representing
                                        a tic tac toe board, after a move
                                        has been made.
                               - (char) A single character of the the
                                        player that just moved.
   Helper Function Outputs (1): - (char) A string indicating the outcome
                                         of the turn.

   The helper function moveEvaluator takes in a 3x3 character array of a
   tic tac toe board after a move has been made, with spaces used to 
   represent the empty spaces on the board, and a single character of the 
   player who just went. This 2nd input will be a string of either 'x' or 
   'o'. This helper function will then output the outcome of that turn: if
   it was player X's turn, then the two possible outcomes are 'Player X
   Wins!' or 'Your turn, player O.' Similarly, if it was player O's turn,
   then the two possible outcomes are 'Player O Wins!' or 'Your turn,
   player X.'
```

So this basically does half my function for me. I seem to have this working thanks to Hoki :)

```
    function[Move_Choices] = ticTacToeTurn(Board, str)

 charBoard = reshape(char(Board) , 3 , 3 ) ;
 PlayerSymbol = str ;

%  Find the indices of possible move
Move_Choices = find(ismember(Board, ' '));

% // count them
nChoices = numel(Move_Choices) ;

% // pre-allocate output
outcome = cell(nChoices,1) ;
Options = '';
Strings = '';
% // Get outcome for each possible postition
for iSlot = 1:nChoices
   PossibleBoard = charBoard ; % // copy the initial board
   PossibleBoard(Move_Choices(iSlot) ) = PlayerSymbol;% // Add an 'x' at one of the empty position
   disp(PossibleBoard) ; % display the currently played board / optional, just for your information
 PossibleBoard = char(PossibleBoard);
  outcome = moveEvaluator(PossibleBoard, str);
    Strings = [Strings {outcome}];
end
for iSlot = 1:nChoices
   PossibleBoard = charBoard ; % // copy the initial board
   PossibleBoard(Move_Choices(iSlot) ) = PlayerSymbol;% // Add an 'x' at one of the empty position
   disp(PossibleBoard) ; % display the currently played board / optional, just for your information
 PossibleBoard = cellstr(PossibleBoard);
  Options = [Options, {PossibleBoard}];
end
Move_Choices = [Options;Strings]; %// Here's my issue. This outputs a cell, but the cellstr function separated the x's and o's into cells of three. I need each spot to be their own cell :/
end
```

I just need it to fill in the one x in either slot, not both. Furthermore, I need to do is figure out how to use the helper function from here to output what the possible string options there are.

```
Testcases:
 board1 = { 'x' 'o' 'x'
                'o' 'x' 'o'
                  'o' ' ' ' ' }
move1 = 'x'
possibleMoves1 = ticTacToeTurn(board1,move1)
```

This should give be a 2x2 cell that looks like:

```
Cell (1,1) This is a cell inside a cell. All of the 'x' and 'o's are a separate cell
{'x''o' 'x'
'o' 'x' 'o'
'o' 'x' ' '}
Cell (2,1) looks is the string that says "Your move, Player O"

Cell (1,2) Should be 
{ 'x'   'o' 'x'
'o' 'x' 'o'
'o'     ' ' 'x'}
 Cell (2, 2) looks is the string that says "Player X wins!'
```

I tried to look at the code for the evaluator function, but it's apparently a p file so I'm not too sure what to do. Any help would be appreciated :) Let me know if I missed anything. Should be all.

Comment: Since this is homework I want to be a little bit careful when I answer not to reveal to much (you teacher does also know about SO). But I guess that you are not interested in all possible board, but merely the next move. However, you may want to consider using one or two for loops (matlab uses columnwise indexing which mean that you can get element board{2,2} by typing board{5} otherwise you need 2 for loops). Use a cell array or struct array to store boards. then you add an element to the container you select for every `' '` in your board (every element is a board with a possible move).

Comment: @patrik My teacher doesn't even check the homework lol and the TAs don't care. As long as some of the code is mine, they could careless. With that being said, I understand column indexing. I converted my board into a string to try and make changing the ' ' easier. I'm terrible with for loops though, but I'm not sure how to use a while loop here. Or how to add the elements in one at a time and not in a consecutive order (Where it just fills up all the spaces).

Comment: @patrik I feel like my main struggle right now is using the helper function though. I can eventually toy around with for and while-loops and get the board to work, but it's the helper function that has thrown me for a real loop.

Comment: try `test = moveEvaluator(['xox';'oxo';'ox '],'x')` and look at the result, it should give you a clue on how to use the helper function.

Comment: But how do I put that into my original function ?

Comment: one step at a time, execute it in the command window and try to understand what you are sending in and the result you are receiving. If you understand that you'll know how to use it in your function.

Comment: I understand it's telling me that if I put an 'x' in the empty space, it's Player O's turn. That's what it says. (Though technically it should be a tie, but that's not an output option for this problem so infinite gameplay I suppose). I still don't understand how to actually use it. They usually get tacked on at the bottom

Comment: what about `test = moveEvaluator(['xox';'oxo';'o x'],'x')` ... notice the difference (_in input as well as output_)?

Comment: I think I correctly used it. Still a little messed up on my for-loop though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, seeing you tried a bit by yourself I'll point you in the final direction. This is not a "function" and so it is not a direct answer to your assignment but it includes the complete resolution of the problem. You just have to repackage it into your function.

```
%% // Initial conditions
Board = {'x' 'o' 'x'
         'o' 'x' 'o'
         'o' ' ' ' ' };
charBoard = reshape( char(Board) , 3 , 3 ) ;
PlayerSymbol = 'x' ;

%% // Resolution
% // Find the indices of possible move
Move_Choices = find(ismember(Board, ' '));

% // count them
nChoices = numel(Move_Choices) ;

% // pre-allocate output
outcome = cell(nChoices,1) ;

% // Get outcome for each possible postition
for iSlot = 1:nChoices
   PossibleBoard = charBoard ; % // copy the initial board
   PossibleBoard( Move_Choices(iSlot) ) = PlayerSymbol ; % // Add an 'x' at one of the empty position
   disp(PossibleBoard) ; % display the currently played board / optional, just for your information
   outcome(iSlot) = moveEvaluator( PossibleBoard , PlayerSymbol ) ;
end
```

A bit of advice: Matlab is an *interpreted* language. This type of programming language has its pro and cons, but it is great for one thing, you can execute lines of code and directly see the result without the need for a complex debugger.

So you can try many different expressions and refine it until the output is what you are looking for. Seeing the way your initial code was organised, it looks like you could benefit a lot from that. Try to solve your problem bit by bit in the base workspace first until you get a good grasp on your problem and its solution. At this stage it will be a lot easier to put it into a function (just have to work out the input/output, but the core of the calculations is already solved).

Comment: Those final words about `MATLAB` as a very easy-to-use and intuitive software platform are very apt and must help OP a lot with the learning process. +1 on that

Comment: I tried that. I had it done like six different ways. I'm just not really good at this whole programming thing. I'm more into biology. Makes more sense to me.

Comment: @Hoki I'm getting a weird error with the last line. Outcome isn't working. The function complains that "Conversion to cell from char is not possible." but I'm not sure why? They're all in char form .-. I haven't even constructed my final output yet. I've altered your code a little, but nothing too crazy.

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed most of it. Just got some cell-ception going on. Just kidding no I don't. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @JessicaMarie, This last line is the only one I couldn't try by myself since I don't have your helper function. It is probably a cell assignment issue. Try to replace `outcome(iSlot)=` by `outcome{iSlot}=`.

Comment: I managed to get most of it working. I just have my um possibleBoards are a character, but I need it to be a cell array. So I have to convert back into that form.

Comment: @Hoki Any suggestions on how to convert my board into a cell array where each slot is it's own cell? cellstr didn't work

Comment: something around these lines `reshape( cellstr(charBoard(:)) , 3,3 )`